# Native Android Crash SIGNAL 11(SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

How to debug a `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3634323064373235` in Android JNI?

I have tried using debugger to find out the root cause but the app is getting crashed randomly (i.e. not at any fixed line)

What I am trying to achieve is to call Java Keystore classes from JNI side.

My question is how can I debug a native crash and what could be the possible reasons for it?

UPDATE:
[NATIVE STACK TRACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWOfQ.jpg)

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emu64a:13/TE1A.220922.012/9302419:userdebug/dev-keys'
#00 0x000000000000b214 /system/lib64/libnativedisplay.so (void std::__1::__tree_remove<std::__1::__tree_node_base<void*>*>(std::__1::__tree_node_base<void*>*, std::__1::__tree_node_base<void*>*)+248) (BuildId: 6387f9e494e4333099eccbb0942e39fb)
#01 0x000000000000a418 /system/lib64/libnativedisplay.so (android::Choreographer::registerStartTime() const+244) (BuildId: 6387f9e494e4333099eccbb0942e39fb)
#02 0x000000000000a290 /system/lib64/libnativedisplay.so (android::Choreographer::dispatchVsync(long, android::PhysicalDisplayId, unsigned int, android::gui::VsyncEventData)+652) (BuildId: 6387f9e494e4333099eccbb0942e39fb)
#03 0x00000000000acb5c /system/lib64/libgui.so (android::DisplayEventDispatcher::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+844) (BuildId: 383a37b5342fd0249afb25e7134deb33)
#04 0x000000000024eac8 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::choreographerCallback(int, int, void*)+32) (BuildId: 5e787210ce0f171dbee073e4a14a376c)
#05 0x0000000000011074 /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+808) (BuildId: 5a0d720732600c94ad8354a1188e9f52)
#06 0x000000000057c4c0 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+220) (BuildId: 5e787210ce0f171dbee073e4a14a376c)
#07 0x00000000000148e8 /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+528) (BuildId: 5a0d720732600c94ad8354a1188e9f52)
#08 0x00000000000b63b0 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
#09 0x00000000000530b8 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
Crash dump is completed
```

Comment: That means native C code crashed by accessing an illegal address.  There should be a native stack trace nearby in the logs with more details.  But without that data, we can't help you any more than that.  The only thing I can say is that it's actually following an invalid pointer and not dereferencing a null (the address isn't 0), so it's either a pointer error or array access error in the native C code

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for the reply! I have attached native stack trace. Can you please have a look on it?